# object with array type string causing a typeError

Tags: javascript

The best way to explain this is just to show you.

```
var condition = 70;
var formnames = new Array("wheelcheckbox1", "wheelcheckbox2","spokecheckbox","spokecheckbox2","tirecheckbox","tirecheckbox2","tirecheckbox3");

formnames.forEach(function(entry) {
   console.log(obj.entry);
   if(obj.entry == "") {
       condition = condition - 10;
   }
});
```

as you can see I used the console log to show how it needs to work
as that works perfect, however, using the array causes an error as 
they're **strings and not what the obj wants**, it wants text without it being a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Code should be posted **here**; the site has ample provisions for it.

Comment: Should be `obj[entry]` not `obj.entry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for..in` [should not](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#array.general) be used to iterate over an array. Consider using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead.

Comment: What does the error message said? Could You fix it?

Comment: well with the    obj.entry it comes out as undefined

Comment: well obj.any of the things in the array works great for instance,   obj.wheelcheckbox1 works perfect, just well i use an array of strings it doesn't work at all

Comment: Oh, there's `obj` somewhere outside of the posted code. Then Pointy's comment above is correct.